# Strapi's Upload Plugin renames font's extension to false

Tags: node.js, mime-types, file-type, strapi

I can't seem to figure out why Strapi is returning a filetype of false instead of the original. This seems to only happen for files other than images.

The upload is working fine... it's just not using the correct filetype to in the response.

This is what I'm doing:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("files", e.target.files[0]);
axios
  .post(apiUrl + '/upload', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Cookies.get("jwt")
    }
  }).catch(error => { console.log(error); // Handle error
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

This is my filename:

```
font.ttf
```

This is my response:

```json
data: {
  {
    alternativeText: null
    caption: null
    created_at: "2020-05-25T20:48:33.910Z"
    ext: ".bin"
    formats: null
    hash: "font_c02e2b80d7"
    height: null
    id: 29
    mime: "application/octet-stream"
    name: "font"
    previewUrl: null
    provider: "local"
    provider_metadata: null
    related: []
    size: 158.17
    updated_at: "2020-05-25T20:48:33.910Z"
    url: "/uploads/font_c02e2b80d7.bin"
    width: null
  }
}
```

Comment: I have very similar problem. When I upload audio recording file with extension .amr Strapi returns file with extension FALSE. Anybody has any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?